# Adding values from HashSet to 2D Matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, set

I have a Map structure that contains an Integer as a key and a set of Objects as the values. However, I have overriden the toString method to get the Integer values of the values. So, example, the Map would look like

`Key: 1 Values: [1, 2, 4]`

I am having a bit trouble constructing a 2D Matrix out out this Map Structure. When I am looping through, I am checking to see if my iterator value is a key in the Map but I am having trouble checking to see if the second iterator is equal to the set value. This is the part of the code in question

```
for (int i = 1; i < this.adjacencyMatrix[0].length; i++) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
System.out.println();
for (int i = 1; i < this.adjacencyMatrix.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
    for (int j = 1; j < this.adjacencyMatrix[i].length; j++) {
        if (this.nodes.containsKey(i)) {
            // Handle the set
            this.adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = 1;
        } else {
            this.adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
        System.out.print(this.adjacencyMatrix[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

My matrix right now will print 1's for the entire row of the map keys.

Example, if 4 is a key, the entire 10 rows will all be printing 1. However, say I have a mapping like 4-- [1, 2, 4] only 1, 2, 4 should have 1's in the given row, all the rest should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

The if-condition (containsKey) is true (or false) for *every* step of the inner loop.

The inner loop should be replaced by two loops: First loop on the index j and initialize all values to 0. Then iterate on the elements in the nodes set, take each value and use it as index:

```
adjacencyMatrix[i][value] = 1
```